# Render repeating components in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to refactor my following code to display multiple icons, using a loop.
I have tried looking for examples but so far I have found map being used on arrays, but I don't have array or any collection.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Icon
          type="FontAwesome"
          name="star"
          style={{ fontSize: 30, color: '#f1c40f' }}
        />
        <Icon
          type="FontAwesome"
          name="star"
          style={{ fontSize: 30, color: '#f1c40f' }}
        />
        <Icon
          type="FontAwesome"
          name="star"
          style={{ fontSize: 30, color: '#f1c40f' }}
        />
        <Icon
          type="FontAwesome"
          name="star"
          style={{ fontSize: 30, color: '#f1c40f' }}
        />
        <Icon
          type="FontAwesome"
          name="star"
          style={{ fontSize: 30, color: '#f1c40f' }}
        />
</View>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I rather would use [`react-native-star-rating`](https://github.com/djchie/react-native-star-rating) package, which handles that for you, also it covers halve stars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function which returns an array of Icon tags to render these stars,Check following code segment.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
createStars = () => {
 let stars = []

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

      stars.push(<Icon
          type="FontAwesome"
          name="star"
          style={{ fontSize: 30, color: '#f1c40f' }}
        />)
    }
    return stars
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        {this.createStars()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Split it into small functions

```
const renderIcon = () => <Icon
  type="FontAwesome"
  name="star"
  style={{ fontSize: 30, color: '#f1c40f' }}
/>;

const renderIcons = num => [...Array(num)].map(renderIcon);

<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
  {renderIcons(5)}
  {renderIcons(4)}
  {renderIcons(3)}
  {renderIcons(2)}
  {renderIcons(1)}
</View>
```

You can take it further and add `name` `style` to `renderIcon`

Comment: This answer seems definitely cool, but you can also use `Array(num).fill(num)` instead of `[...Array(num)]`, giving you more options.

Comment: @CarlosAbraham Thank you, but whats the options it gives us ?

Comment: `[...Array(3)]` creates an empty array of size 3, with undefined values in it, you can do `Array(3)` and it would be the same thing. It is just another option, I wanted to share :)

Comment: @CarlosAbraham Ah my bad, I thought you meant it give us more options in `renderIcons` woops, Thanks for sharing